# What is Endpoint for JFROG Artifactory over HTTPS

Tags: tomcat, https, artifactory

I tried the steps listed in the question [How to configure jfrog Artifactory web interface to use https rather than http](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67216333/how-to-configure-jfrog-artifactory-web-interface-to-use-https-rather-than-http/77662682?noredirect=1#comment136916718_77662682) and the linked answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/68750332/23103935 :

- Find the system.full-template.yaml that was delivered with the new version 7.17.11 in /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/etc
- Copy the relevant artifactory/tomcat/httpsConnector block to system.yaml
- Make it enabled, port 8443, change the certificate and key paths to the absolute paths
- Save the file
- restart Artifactory

Now, going to http://my-artifactory-ip:8082 correctly works in the browser like before. But none of the https variations seem to get through - not https://my-artifactory-ip:8082, or https://my-artifactory-ip:443, or http://my-artifactory-ip:8443.

No errors in catalina logs.

What would the new endpoint be to hit the UI?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try `https://my-artifactory-ip:8443/artifactory` ?

If you've configured `Artifactory` to use `HTTPS` on port 8443 and restarted it successfully, you should be able to access the Artifactory web interface using the following URL:

`https://my-artifactory-ip:8443/artifactory`

If its still doesn't work, check if 8443 is free of use and confirm that there are no other `processes` or `services` running on port 8443, and that the `firewall` on your server allows incoming connections on this port.

After that i would try to access it with incognito to rule out browser cache issues.

The last thing i can think of is ensuring that the `SSL certificate` you configured in `Artifactory` is valid and not expired, and that the paths for certificate and key are valid in the `system.yaml` file